# Is there a way to use the new go embed feature with echo?

Tags: go, embed, go-echo

Is there a way to use the new go embed feature with echo?
I would like to serve files with the echo static middleware from files embedded with go embed.
https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/
https://echo.labstack.com/guide/static-files

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1755) links to a [gist from Mark Wolfe](https://gist.github.com/wolfeidau/9f43e3f44cdb7a5f77405d3aa60421fc) that demonstrates a pretty straight forward approach. The core of the approach is:

```golang
// content holds our static web server content.
//go:embed static/*
var content embed.FS

var contentHandler = echo.WrapHandler(http.FileServer(http.FS(content)))
// The embedded files will all be in the '/static' folder so need to rewrite the request (could also do this with fs.Sub)
var contentRewrite = middleware.Rewrite(map[string]string{"/*": "/static/$1"})

func SetupRoutes(...) {
   e.GET("/*", contentHandler, contentRewrite)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was already trying Mark Wolf's suggestion, I didn't succeed in the beginning. But your answer helped me try one more time, so when I build the executable via `` go build '' the templates folder is included but the assets folder is not included.